# How to stop a container using ssh connection?

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have this error when I try to stop a container with `sudo docker stop pg`:

> Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: pg: Cannot kill container 9cead43f288336d418e91105d5c9a4e0858794c96ebd167e5e92784d8ed1eab2: unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "permission denied"

When we run `docker-compose up -d` then everything works fine but when we run `docker-compose down` or `docker-compose restart` then we got permission denied error.

Comment: What command did you execute exactly to stop the container?

Comment: sudo docker stop pg

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `apparmor` it's blocking the access, you can try stop it and try again to stop the container:

```
sudo systemctl stop apparmor && systemctl disable apparmor
sudo docker stop pg
```

And then run it again with the flag:

```
--security-opt apparmor=unconfined
```

Comment: i have this error after run comands  above:


$ sudo docker stop odoopgu

Error response from daemon: cannot stop container: odoopgu: Cannot kill container e63fc4135d0fea4611304cb8f1c80dbaeca87559ca9f9dd05bc785fe208412fa: unknown error after kill: docker-runc did not terminate sucessfully: container_linux.go:393: signaling init process caused "permission denied"
: unknown